# Generate pdf with "extract page" authorization

Tags: pdftex, pdf

is there a way to generate a PDF with the security option "extract page" as authorized? My University requires it for my thesis and I am having a hard time here. Here is a minimal working example for which Adobe indicates in File>Parameter>Security that "extract page" is not authorized in the generated PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

    document used to test security settings

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

PS : I do not have Adobe Pro...

Comment: I don't think that you can extract pages with adobe reader, you will need adobe pro (when I open your file with it  extracting pages is allowed).

Comment: Could you check with a different pdf, for example generated from Microsoft Word or from LibreOffice, if the option in Adobe is available for those files? Or maybe try with an already published thesis from somebody else (which presumably has passed the university requirements). Also, you could send your draft to the university and ask them to check if it is ok or not, to confirm that there actually is a problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: If your university requires security on PDFs, and ONLY Adobe Pro can provide security, they need to provide access to Adobe Pro.  Perhaps a secretary?

Comment: Thank you for your really good advice! Indeed I have the same problem with a pdf generated with OpenOffice. I ended up downloading a free trial for Adobe Pro and then the pdf appears as unprotected (as should), so I guess this is only a limitation for the free version. I will post an answer based on other post I read to help any with the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a PDF generated by LaTeX has no protection. In Adobe Reader DC, the security "extract page" appears as not authorized only because it is unavailable for this free version.

If you are experiencing troubles with a tool based on page extraction (such as plagiarism detection tool, as I was), you can identify which pages are at fault by following these steps:

1. download Adobe Pro (which is free for the first 7 days)
2. print your document using the printer "Abode pdf", which will try to extract it page by page
3. if a pdf is produced, the problem does not lie in the extraction process. If no pdf is produced, you get a log report (text file), written *after* each page extracted so you can nail the first page at fault (the one for which Adobe has not been able to proceed).

You can also print only part of the document to analyze further the common point between each page leading to errors and then fix the document.

In my case, **the problem lied in the color gradients defined in TikZ** with the `\shade` command, which Adobe has troubles dealing with. I had to convert some figure in png for the document to be accepted by the plagiarism detection tool.

I hope this can help others!